# shrink elements with flexbox when browser shrinks

Tags: html, css

I'm facing an annoying issue with flexbox (I'm a beginner).

As you can see here: https://codepen.io/guy-ben-yeshaya/pen/NeqjbG

1) Is it possible, while shrinking the browser until certain point, that the red box and the text will shrink all together (without setting the text size to VW, because it becomes too small on mobile size), instead of the elements go under each other?

2)Why when shrinking the browser to a phone size, the text doesn't become responsive?

Thanks alot for reading and helping!

```css
.section-1{

    margin-top: 200px;
    display:flex;

    text-align: left;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.headertext1{
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: #1CD2D5;
    font-size: 80px;
}

.headersubtext{
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}



.btn{
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-color: #1CD2D5;
    background: #1CD2D5;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'dosis';
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-1">
          <div class="1 flex1">
            <h1 class="headertext1"><b>BARAN</b>GLOBAL</h1>
            <h3 class="headersubtext">Real Estate and consultant agency. <br>A link to your future thourgh intelligent investing.</h3>
           
              <a href="#section-2" class="btn"><b>Learn More</b></a>
          </div>
          <div class="2 flex1">
              <div class="box"></div>
             
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you will need `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way to control the breaking? For example: the word BARANGLOBAL to be broken to BARAN & GLOBAL ?

Comment: you can read about `word-break` you will find other values that may help you

Comment: I will. Do you know about a method to shrink 2 elements (picture and text) while shrinking the browser?